# Наследование в JQuery

Tags: jquery

Как реализовать наследование в JQuery? Пока что остановился на том, что нужно использовать jquery.widget из jquery.core вместо стандартоного создания плагина. Если еще какие-то решения, кроме самописных "велосипедов"?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете JQuery, то присмотритесь к [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

В jQuery, к сожалению, нет стандартных возможностей для работы с иерархиями классов. Поэтому либо "самописные велосипеды", либо сторонние библиотеки. Например, [JSClass](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) или 
[Joose](http://joose.it/).